# Perform one of many substitutions in many files at two specific locations

Tags: text-processing

I have about a hundred thousand files, for each file I want to do the following:

Between the fifth and sixth character in the file with the following ascii code: `0x1f`, a string is present. Now I want the application to open a specific file containing a list of all the substitutions, see later for the format of that substitutions file. If the substitution is not in the file, write the filename to stderr so I can manually fix that one later. Now between the 16th and 17th character with ascii code `0x1f` the thing to substitute will appear again, however this time the field is not just the thing to substitute, but a string of html containing whatever shall be substituted from one to several times. I only want the first occurence in that field replaced.

The format of the substitutions file is fairly simple, each substitution is on its own line and they're separated by a space. They're ordered by the length of the thing to substitute.

---

**Example**

Substitutions file:

```
CCCC 3
BCC 233
CCA 331
CCB 332
ACC 133
AA 11
AB 12
BA 21
BB 22
CC 33
A 1
B 2
```

Note that it's not guaranteed to be characters and numbers like above, that's just an example and the might contain UTF-8.

File: (0x1f characters are written as ^_ in the following example)

```
field1^_field2^_field3^_field4^_field5^_BB^_field7^_hai
this field contains a newline^_some UTF-8オイ^_the next field is empty^_^_
another newline^_field14^_field15^_<b>BB</b>stuff BB^_the previous field contains something to replace^_^_^_more fields...
```

This file would get turned into

```
field1^_field2^_field3^_field4^_field5^_22^_field7^_hai
this field contains a newline^_some UTF-8オイ^_the next field is empty^_^_
another newline^_field14^_field15^_<b>22</b>stuff BB^_the previous field contains something to replace^_^_^_more fields...
```

I have uploaded a real example of my input [here](http://pastebin.com/3j5W20fz). The desired output from that file is [here](http://pastebin.com/g5MjJLxJ) (`RYO` should be replaced by `リョ`).

---

**A little background**
Some idiot decided that instead of creating separate columns in our database, he made a single column and separated the fields with the 0x1f character. He also decided that it's OK to duplicate the information I want to change in two different fields. I extracted the information from the database into a file pr. row containing just the column with the fields, as I suspect that is easier to work with, however if you can make a statement I can give to a SQLite database, that's fine too.

Comment: @Kristoffer Ryhl: Create a temporary table with columns corresponding to the fields, and populate it from the first table.  Run a (SQL) join and do the substitutions.  Then (string) join the columns in the affected lines by `0x1f`, and write them back to the initial table.  Finally drop the temporary table.  Well, I didn't say it would be nice. :)

Comment: @lcd047 How does that deal with cases that need manual intervention? I would like to be told about them.

Comment: @Kristoffer Ryhl: Run a query on the new table to find the lines that need manual intervention, and save them or whatever.  Then do the substitutions.

Comment: Yeah okay, I'll do the perl solution, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Perl script should do it. I tested on the example you had on pastebin and it works as expected:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;

my %k; ## This hash will store the target/replacement pairs
## Read the list of replacements
open(my $r,"$ARGV[0]")||die "Couldn't open replacements list\n";
while(<$r>){
    chomp;
    my @F=split(/\s+/);
    $k{$F[0]}=$F[1]
}
close($r);
$/=undef;

open(my $fh, "$ARGV[1]")||die "Couldn't open input file\n";
while(<$fh>){
    ## Read the entire file at once
    $/=undef;
    my @F=split(/\x1f/);
    ## If this exists in the replacements list
    if (defined($k{$F[5]})) {
        ## Modify the 17th field. This will only replace the first
        ## occurence. Use 's///g' for all. 
        $F[16]=~s/$F[5]/$k{$F[5]}/;
        ## Replace the 6th field
        $F[5]=$k{$F[5]};

    }
    ## If it doesn't
    else {
        ## Print the file name to STDERR unless the 5th field
        ## was empty.
        print STDERR "Problematic file: $ARGV[1]\n" unless $F[5]=~/^\s*$/;
    }
    ## print each field separated by '0x1f' again.
    print join "\x1f",@F;


}
close($fh);
```

Save that as `fixidiocy.pl` in your `$HOME` directory, and `cd` into the directory containing the target files. Now, run it on each file, giving the file name and the path to the replacements file as arguments:

```
for file in *; do 
    perl ~/fixidiocy.pl /path/to/replacements "$file" > "$file".fixed
done
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected, only 324 problems out of 210374 files.

Comment: If you can make it do nothing to the file if the sixth field was empty, it seems  that would fix most of the problematic files.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl done, see update. Now file names whose 6th field was empty are not printed.

Comment: Okay, the problems have been reduced to 63 and it doesn't seem like the remaining problematic files are solvable without manual intervention. Thanks for your time.